# find with regex and fixed quantifier

Tags: regex

I have files in format `name with spaeces.xxx.txt` where `xxx` are three digits. I want to match them with `find`. I have tried:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex '.*\.[0-9]{3}\.txt'
```

but that does not work. 
This does not work either:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex '.*[0-9]{3}\.txt'
```

This one:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex '.*[0-9]\.txt'
```

works and it seems there is a problem with repeat operator. I tested the regex in online testers and it does match my filenames. I have tried o change `-regextype` to a few values without any luck. The manual says that by default, `find` uses `emacs` style regex, the wiki for `emacs` says it does know the fixed quantifier, so I am lost.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried with `-regextype egrep` ? Seems to work for me : https://ideone.com/yostBm

Comment: Interesting, `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex '.*\.[0-9]{3}\.txt' -regextyoe sed` does not work but `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regextype sed -regex '.*\.[0-9]{3}\.txt'` does, ie. it does depend where one puts the `-regextype` option.

Comment: `-regextype type Changes the regular expression syntax understood by -regex and -iregex tests which occur later on the command line.` Maybe surprising, but documented ;) You may want to post that as a solution, it could save some troubles to others with a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex '\.[0-9]\{3\}\.txt'
```

You can also use `grep`:

```
find . * | grep -P "\.[0-9]{3}\.txt"
```